# Use WebRTC with WebWorker

Tags: webrtc, web-worker

I am interested in to use webrtc with webworker. 
Is it possible?

I tried it but it did not work because it did not find the "window"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the specifications [[1](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#dom-navigator), [2](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#interface-definition)], `navigator.mediaDevices` and `RTCPeerConnection` are not defined for web workers, so WebRTC shouldn't be available on web workers for now.

For [[1](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#dom-navigator)], `navigator.mediaDevices` attribute is defined on `Navigator` interface for window, but not on `WorkerNavigator` interface for web worker.

For [[2](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#interface-definition)], `RTCPeerConnection` interface is exposed to window (`[Exposed=Window]`), but not to web worker (`[Exposed=Worker]`).

Answer (score 0):

The worker does not need to handle the webrtc connection it gets handeled outside the render process anyway and connected via MOJO:IPC internal so you can simply target from the render process a sharedArrayBuffer if your working in a secure context. Then you create a worker passing it the same arrayBuffer that u use to write out the WebRTC data.

Also wasm by design works in a worker on sharedMemory that means as soon as you do any processing in wasm your working in a worker.

It makes no sense to move WebRTC into a webworker as the final goal is to not copy data between the render process and what ever sends it via remote.

to eneable low latency copying data would destroy that.