# Can a PWA run a WebRTC connection in the background?

Tags: webrtc, progressive-web-apps

I am building an app which will communicate with the other devices in my office network through WebRTC. For mobile phones in the network, I want to use a PWA for this job.

Can PWAs have a background service running which communicates with other devices over WebRTC?

Comment: Should be able to. Is there something you have tried that is not working?

Comment: @Mathias Thanks. And no not really, we don't have much experience with PWAs or WebRTC (coming from a server-client web background). So wanted to make sure before diving in.

Comment: I have no experience in doing so either, so best keep asking. I was just wondering if there was a problem to be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

For posterity, as of date WebRTC is not available in ServiceWorkers.
See: [Use WebRTC with WebWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54208957/use-webrtc-with-webworker)

It has been a request for a few years and may or may not be implemented in the future.

W3C Requests for WebRTC in ServiceWorker:

- https://github.com/w3c/webrtc-pc/issues/230
- https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1522

The current alternative it to use Transferable Streams. Of date Chrome supports Transferable streams.

https://github.com/whatwg/streams/blob/main/transferable-streams-explainer.md

Transferable Stream JS implementations

- https://github.com/MattiasBuelens/remote-web-streams
- https://github.com/Seedess/postmessage-transferable-stream

For browsers not supporting transferable streams you can use transferable ArrayBuffer.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Transferable_objects

You'll need to create the WebRTC channel in the window (non-worker) scope and transfer the `Stream` or `ArrayBuffer` to the ServiceWorker to complete the request.

Answer (score 2):

You might technically be able to connect WebRTC in a service worker but they [intentionally have short lifespans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29750936/26406) so the connection wouldn't last more than a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

yes works fine with Android, but getUserMedia won't work with PWA i mean in standalone mode